# creating eh-pairs in a semiconductor -> conduction or valence band?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

When a beam ray respectively a photon creates an electron-hole pair in a semiconductor, e.g. for silicon the ionization energy is 3.6 eV, is the electron then directly in the conduction band? So does this photon energy 3.6 ionize and lift the electron up?

Comment: If you give an electron at the top of the valence band at k=0 the 3.6eV from a photon, yes, it will go straight up to the conduction band at k=0, forming an electron-hole pair, yes. You should go find Pankove in your local library...

Comment: @JonCuster, isn't that an answer, albeit brief, rather than a comment?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri - well, Ben has been asking a number of variations on this, with one of his questions actually showing the transition in question. The formation of an electron-hole pair is covered well in many introductory texts.